# Import React library Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, webpacker, react-rails

Having knowledge of Ruby, I decided to start developing a web application with RoR.Since I didn't find a front-end framework for RoR, I decided to go for React.
That's how I found the gem `react-rails`.

However, I don't know how to import a React library into my RoR application. I would like to import the `SemanticUI` library.

How do I proceed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions on how to set up React and Webpack through this repo: https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails

If so, you can install SemanticUI from this documentation (https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage/) using Yarn.